# Oracle Time Comparisons

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic, to-char

Is Oracle (10g) doing a proper TIME comparison here, or do I need to convert to decimal time and then compare? E.g.,

```
IF (SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate,'HH24:MI:SS') from dual) <= '15:00'
THEN (...)
```

Thanks.

Comment: This just compares two strings. Does that even execute? It is neither SQL nor PL/SQL. Try something like this: `IF SYSDATE <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) + (15/24) THEN ...`

Comment: If you mean "the time must be *on or before* 3pm" then you need "<= '15:00:00'". If you mean "the time must be *before* 3pm" then you could have done "TO_CHAR(sysdate,'HH24') < '15'"

Answer (score 10):

```
IF (sysdate <= trunc(sysdate)+15/24)
THEN (...)
```

should do the trick...

Comment: +1 Got in there first with of what was to be the last part my answer!

Comment: 5/8 would be even better (says the math major) ;-)

Comment: @DavidFaber, it's less obvious what you're doing though. I always use modular arithmetic mod-24 - to maths it up slightly :-), when doing hour calculations as it's very clear what's going on.

Comment: Does trunc(sysdate) effectively create a time of "0", to which 15/24 is added, thus making a time of 15?

Comment: Yes.  TRUNC(date) "rounds-down" the date to midnight (00:00:00).  Adding 15/24 is adding 15 hours, thus taking you to 15:00:00.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do a `select` in an `if` statement, but you can do a direct comparison to sysdate. If you're doing it like this it would probably be better to use a number rather than relying on implicit conversion. You also don't need the extra minutes etc. Something like,

```
begin

   if to_number(to_char(sysdate,'HH24')) <= 15 then
      -- do something
   end if;

end;
```

If you did want to use the minutes then by converting it into a string without the colon you can do a more direct comparison. As long as the date / time is converted in 24 hour format without extras and in reverse, year, month, day, hour etc comparisons will always be accurate, e.g.

```
begin

   if to_char(sysdate,'HH24MI') <= '1515' then
      -- do something
   end if;

end;
```

However, it's often best to do date comparisons as @cagcowboy has just posted before I got there!

Answer (score 1):

use the following code

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24MI') INTO V_SYS_TIME FROM DUAL;

IF V_SYS_TIME BETWEEN V1_TIME AND V2_TIME THEN 
(....)
```

Comment: Same as: "IF TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24MI') BETWEEN V1_TIME AND V2_TIME THEN" but slower