# ObjectQuery, passing Time in Where clause

Tags: c#, oracle, objectquery

How can I construct the Where clause of the ObjectQuery where I will be querying for the Time part only of a DateTime column? I've tried the following but it's not working. I get an invalid exception on Convert.

```
 ObjectQuery<Item> _Query = ItemEntities.CreateQuery<Item>("Item");
_Query = _Query.Where("Convert(VARCHAR,it.START_TIME,114) > '{0}'", startTime.TimeOfDay);
```

Also, I'm using Oracle as database. So I tried `to_char` instead of convert and still I get the same error.

Thanks.

Comment: [Oracle time comparisons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625323/oracle-time-comparisons)?

Comment: My problem is in the construction of the query. Since I'm using ObjectQuery to retrieve data from database, I need how to get the TIME part of it.START_TIME (which is a datetime column). I tried _Query.Where("TO_CHAR(it.START_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss')... but I also get an exception.

Comment: Add an exception that you're getting.

Comment: "'to_char' cannot be resolved into a valid type or function

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the time portion from the date using `TO_CHAR` and then subsequently converting it to a system type e.g.

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(it.START_TIME,'HH24:MI:SS'), 'hh24:mi:ss') from dual
```

If `ObjectQuery` doesn't support `TO_CHAR` you try using `Extract` and build up the time manually e.g.

```
TO_DATE(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM it.START_TIME) || ':' || EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM it.START_TIME) || ':' || EXTRACT(SECOND FROM it.START_TIME) FROM DUAL, 'HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: My problem is that ObjectQuery does not recognize TO_CHAR as a valid type or function.